# Sequence Converging to Pi

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this sequence:

$\frac{4}{1}$, $\frac{8}{3}$, $\frac{32}{9}$, $\frac{128}{45}$, ...

Basically, to get the $N$-th member of that sequence: if $N$ is even, then multiply the previous member by $\frac{N}{N+1}$, and if $N$ is odd, then multiply the previous member by $\frac{N+1}{N}$. This sequence has been told me to converge (slowly) to $\pi$.

Now, I figured how to express it formally (but would like someone to confirm it) but I have no clue how to prove it converges to $\pi$.

Can anyone give me a hint?

This is what I got so far but I am not sure it is right...
Thanks in advance for any help..

$a_{n+1}$ = $\frac{N+1}{N}^{-\frac{|n|}{n}}a_{n}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: Thank you Martin! I actually have a further question. How would you relate the Wallis product to this sequence tending to infinity? I noticed the product structure of those values tend to Pi/2. But, in this sequence I have the Nth value (which is one factor of that product structure) which tends to infinity. How would you tie the two? Thanks in advance